# I keep getting "TypeError: Only byte strings can be passed to C code" when trying to run this python ecnrypt

Tags: python, encryption

I keep getting a TypeError when trying to run this encryption code

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES 
import base64
import os


def encryption(privateInfo):
BLOCK_SIZE = 16
PADDING = '{'

pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING

EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s)))

secret = os.urandom(BLOCK_SIZE)
print ('encryption key:', secret)

cipher = AES.new(secret,AES.MODE_CFB)

encoded = EncodeAES(cipher, privateInfo)
print( 'Encrypted string: ', encoded)
```

At first it told me that I needed to specify the mode for the line 
'cipher = AES.new(secret)'. Once I did this it gave me the error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Eddie\source\repos\pycrypto_1\pycrypto_1\pycrypto_1.py", line 19, in encryption
    encoded = EncodeAES(cipher, privateInfo)
  File "C:\Users\Eddie\source\repos\pycrypto_1\pycrypto_1\pycrypto_1.py", line 12, in <lambda>
    EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\Cipher\_mode_cfb.py", line 156, in encrypt
    expect_byte_string(plaintext)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\Cryptodome\Util\_raw_api.py", line 196, in expect_byte_string
    raise TypeError("Only byte strings can be passed to C code")
TypeError: Only byte strings can be passed to C code
```

I will say that the code does successfully print the encryption key. It only gives the error when it gets to the portion of the code that is supposed to print out the encrypted message.

Comment: which one is line 196 of _raw_api.py?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski that line isn't in my code, its apart of pycryptodomex package.

Comment: cipher.encrypt requires a byte string as its argument. cast string to bytes before passing to encrypt.

Comment: @hkyi if this is the line you are referring EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s))). I tried to use encode on it like so EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s.encode('utf-8'))). However it gave me a TypeError: can't concat str to bytes.

Comment: pad = lambda s: bytes(s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING, 'utf-8')  will work.

Comment: @hkyi thanks, you should add it as an answer